# Laravel model mass assignment

Tags: php, laravel

Изучаю Laravel и до конца не могу разобраться в атрибутах 'fillable', 'hidden' и 'guarded' при массовом назначении.

В документации говорится, что при массовом назначении используя 'fillable' 'нечистивые' пользователи могут подменить какой-либо параметр при массовом назначении. Для этого нужно добавить поле которое хочешь защитить в 'guarded' и якобы теперь можно массово назначать 'безопасно'.
Так ли это? Тогда несколько вопросов:

1. Почему бы сразу все поля не вставлять в 'guarded'?
2. Зачем атрибут 'hidden', про него нигде не сказано...
   Заметил что поля добавленные в 'hidden' просто не доступны из глобальной переменной 'Auth'
3. Без заморочек лучше использовать:

`$flight = new Flight;
 $flight->name = $anyname;
 $flight->save();` 
 и всё будет тип-топ?

Comment: 1. Потому что если вы все поля впишите в `guarded` то сами их изменить тоже не сможете, чаще всего туда вписывают `id`.
3. Как вариант, но это не есть массовое назначение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Почему бы сразу все поля не вставлять в 'guarded'?

В `guarded` попадают значения которые не стоило бы добавлять через массовое назначение, вы можете добавить все поля в `guarded` если хотите, но смысла нет в этом если вы будете использовать 3 вариант:

```
$flight = new Flight;
$flight->name = $anyname;
$flight->save();
```

Просто не всегда получается прямо обращаться к методам, да и проще в плане логики и компактности кода работать через массовое назначение.

> 2. Зачем атрибут 'hidden', про него нигде не сказано... Заметил что поля добавленные в 'hidden' просто не доступны из глобальной
>      переменной 'Auth'

Он скрывает с вывода поля, вы смотрели на примере `User`, а вот если вам нужно будет вывести пользователей в массив или json чтобы отдать по API или на фронтенд, вы просто пишите `User:find(1)->toArray()` и все атрибуты будут выведены кроме `hidden`, что сильно упрощает вам работу.

> 3. Без заморочек лучше использовать:

Если вам так удобно - используйте, массовое назначение - это один из вариантов сохранения данных, не обязательно его использовать.

Comment: То есть такие поля, как например: баланс, статус пользователя и тд можно спокойно вставлять в 'guarded' и не опасаясь можно массово назначать?

Comment: Наоборот, если их туда вставить - нельзя будет массово назначать, только как вы описали в 3 варианте.

Comment: @Алексей запрещают от массового присвоения критично важные атрибуты которые вдруг случайно изменит пользователь, хотя в хороших приложениях такого не бывает